# Creating roads using cities skyline api

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cities-skylines-api

Can I create roads of a certain type using cities skyline API, so far I have been trying to find if there is a manager for roads but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repo [CS_ProceduralCities](https://github.com/coder0xff/CS_ProceduralCities) have wrappers for creating roads at Builder.cs

```
 ushort MakeSegment(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Vector3 startDirection, Vector3 endDirection, uint prefabId) {
        {
            var netManager = Singleton<NetManager>.instance;
            ushort segmentId;
            if (netManager.CreateSegment(out segmentId, ref SimulationManager.instance.m_randomizer, PrefabCollection<NetInfo>.GetPrefab(prefabId), GetNode(start), GetNode(end), startDirection, endDirection, SimulationManager.instance.m_currentBuildIndex, SimulationManager.instance.m_currentBuildIndex, false)) {
                ++SimulationManager.instance.m_currentBuildIndex;
                //DebugOutputPanel.AddMessage(PluginManager.MessageType.Warning, "made segment");
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Error creating segment");
            }
            return segmentId;
        }
        ;
    }

    ushort MakeSegment(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, bool flip, uint prefabId) {
        if (flip) {
            var temp = start;
            start = end;
            end = temp;
        }
        var netManager = Singleton<NetManager>.instance;
        ushort segmentId;
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(end.x - start.x, end.y - start.y, end.z - start.z).normalized;
        if (netManager.CreateSegment(out segmentId, ref SimulationManager.instance.m_randomizer, PrefabCollection<NetInfo>.GetPrefab(prefabId), GetNode(start), GetNode(end), direction, -direction, SimulationManager.instance.m_currentBuildIndex, SimulationManager.instance.m_currentBuildIndex, false)) {
            ++SimulationManager.instance.m_currentBuildIndex;
            //DebugOutputPanel.AddMessage(PluginManager.MessageType.Warning, "made segment");
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Error creating segment");
        }
        return segmentId;
    }

    void MakeRoad(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Vector3 startDirection, Vector3 endDirection, bool flip, uint prefabId) {
        DebugOutputPanel.AddMessage(PluginManager.MessageType.Warning, "making bezier road");
        if (flip) {
            Vector3 temp = start;
            start = end;
            end = temp;

            temp = -startDirection;
            startDirection = -endDirection;
            endDirection = temp;
        }
        float length = (end - start).magnitude;
        var curve = new Bezier3(start, start + startDirection * length / 3, end + endDirection * length / 3, end);
        Vector3 priorPos = curve.Position(0);
        Vector3 priorDir = curve.Tangent(0).normalized;
        float t = curve.Travel(0, pitch);
        DebugOutputPanel.AddMessage(PluginManager.MessageType.Warning, t.ToString());

        while (t < .9999) {
            Vector3 pos = curve.Position(t);
            Vector3 dir = curve.Tangent(t);
            MakeSegment(priorPos, pos, priorDir, -dir, prefabId);
            t = curve.Travel(t, pitch);
            DebugOutputPanel.AddMessage(PluginManager.MessageType.Warning, t.ToString());
            priorPos = pos;
            priorDir = dir;
        }
        {
            Vector3 pos = curve.Position(1);
            Vector3 dir = curve.Tangent(1).normalized;
            MakeSegment(priorPos, pos, priorDir, -dir, prefabId);
        }
    }

    void MakeRoad(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, bool flip, uint prefabId) {
        if (flip) {
            Vector3 temp = start;
            start = end;
            end = temp;
        }

        var dir = (end - start).normalized;
        if ((dir.x == 0 || dir.z == 0) && dir.y == 0) {
            if (dir.x > 0) {
                //DebugOutputPanel.AddMessage(PluginManager.MessageType.Warning, "made +x vector road");
                for (float x = start.x; x < end.x; x += pitch) {
                    float clampedIncrement = x + pitch;
                    if (clampedIncrement > end.x) clampedIncrement = end.x;
                    MakeSegment(new Vector3(x, start.y, start.z), new Vector3(clampedIncrement, start.y, start.z), false, prefabId);
                }
            } else if (dir.x < 0) {
                //DebugOutputPanel.AddMessage(PluginManager.MessageType.Warning, "made -x vector road");
                for (float x = start.x; x > end.x; x -= pitch) {
                    float clampedIncrement = x - pitch;
                    if (clampedIncrement < end.x) clampedIncrement = end.x;
                    MakeSegment(new Vector3(x, start.y, start.z), new Vector3(clampedIncrement, start.y, start.z), false, prefabId);
                }
            } else if (dir.z > 0) {
                //DebugOutputPanel.AddMessage(PluginManager.MessageType.Warning, "made +z vector road");
                for (float z = start.z; z < end.z; z += pitch) {
                    float clampedIncrement = z + pitch;
                    if (clampedIncrement > end.z) clampedIncrement = end.z;
                    MakeSegment(new Vector3(start.x, start.y, z), new Vector3(start.x, start.y, clampedIncrement), false, prefabId);
                }
            } else if (dir.z < 0) {
                //DebugOutputPanel.AddMessage(PluginManager.MessageType.Warning, "made -z vector road");
                for (float z = start.z; z > end.z; z -= pitch) {
                    float clampedIncrement = z - pitch;
                    if (clampedIncrement < end.z) clampedIncrement = end.z;
                    MakeSegment(new Vector3(start.x, start.y, z), new Vector3(start.x, start.y, clampedIncrement), false, prefabId);
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception("logic error");
            }
        } else {
            var delta = end - start;
            var direction = delta.normalized;
            var length = delta.magnitude;
            float t = 0;
            for (; t <= length - pitch; t += pitch) {
                MakeSegment(start + direction * t, start + direction * (t + pitch), false, prefabId);
            }
            MakeSegment(start + direction * t, end, false, prefabId);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Modding API for which the documentation is [here](https://skylines.paradoxwikis.com/Modding_API).

Comment: I appreciate your help but the documentation is far from complete and doesn't contain much information except on building the mod dll file. I have found the solution on a repo on GitHub.